# Spy or Mock or whatever ..TableView?

Tags: ios, swift, mocking, stub

I read a book TDD iOS Development and I have a feeling that I do not understand difference between fake/stub/spy/mock words.

Here is an example of code from this book:

```
ItemListDataProviderTests class:
extension ItemListDataProviderTests {
    class MockTableView: UITableView {
        var cellGotDequeued = false
        override func dequeueReusableCell(
            withIdentifier identifier: String,
            for indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            cellGotDequeued = true
            return super.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier,
                                             for: indexPath)
        }
    }
}
```

Here we have mock table view but if we read [Martin Fowler, which say next](https://www.martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html):

- **Dummy** objects are passed around but never actually used. Usually they are just used to fill parameter lists.
- **Fake** objects actually have working implementations, but usually take some shortcut which makes them not suitable for production (an in memory database is a good example).
- **Stubs** provide canned answers to calls made during the test, usually not responding at all to anything outside what's programmed in for the test.
- **Spies** are stubs that also record some information based on how they were called. One form of this might be an email service that records how many messages it was sent.
- **Mocks** are what we are talking about here: objects pre-programmed with expectations which form a specification of the calls they are expected to receive.

But this MockTableView does not look like Mock though. For me it looks like a spy because it has not expectation at all but still it has some info to record.

What is TableView here Mock or Spy or something else?